# Is there a way to make a Form fill x % of the screen?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I wonder if there is a way to, instead of using pixels, adjusting the size of a form in C#? For example make Form1 fill 75% of the screen in width and 80% of the screen in height? I have experimented a bit with reading the Users screen resolution and then adjusting it from there, but I am searching for a different approach. I want to do this to solve the issue with different screen resolution, so I don't have to use scrollbars. Is there a way to do this or should I just keep my scrolls?

Comment: Is this WPF? Windows Forms? ASP.NET?  You need to specify the technology you're talking about.  C# is just the language.

Comment: You'll still have to have scrollbars as a fallback, in case the user's screen is not large enough or you have too much data to display. So since you can't eliminate them completely, what's the point of this? Let the user choose if they want your form to take up the entire screen or not. If they do, there's a handy "maximize" button in the title bar.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use the Load event so you're not affected by automatic form scaling.  Like this:

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
        var scr = Screen.FromPoint(this.Location);
        this.Size = new Size((int)(scr.WorkingArea.Width * 0.75),
                             (int)(scr.WorkingArea.Height * 0.80));
        this.Location = new Point((scr.WorkingArea.Width - this.Width) / 2,
                                  (scr.WorkingArea.Height - this.Height) / 2);
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the resolution of the screen using:

```
Rectangle rect = Screen.AllScreens[0].Bounds;
//Maybe you need to use WorkingArea instead of Bounds.
```

From there you can use the 80% of what you want. More information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.aspx

Comment: Yes, you would definitely want to use [`Screen.WorkingArea`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.workingarea.aspx). That excludes things like the taskbar, docked windows/toolbars, etc.